# El delay de un Timer se modifica misteriosamente al ejecutarse en otra computadora

Tags: java, timer, jpanel

Hice un trabajo práctico para la universidad en el que había que crear un juego dada una librería externa con el *"entorno"* en la que:

Dentro de una clase que hereda de **JPanel** e implementa **`ActionListener`** se crea un objeto **`Timer`** con un delay de **10 milisegundos**.

Dentro de su **`ActionPerformed`**, llama al método **`repaint`** de JPanel.

Dentro de paint, se ejecuta el método **tick** de una instancia de la clase **Juego**.

En el constructor de la clase juego se llama al método **`iniciar`** del JPanel, en el que se instancia el *Timer*.

En mi computadora y en la de los otros dos integrantes del grupo, el juego funciona a unos estables 64(+-1) **fps**. Probé incluso usando el método `tick` solamente para contar **fps** y no hubo variación, o sea que no es una diferencia de rendimiento. Pero al ejecutarlo en la computadora de la universidad funciona a más **fps**.

No se me ocurre cual puede ser la razón. La hipótesis actual es que haya una diferencia en la librería del **JRE** o algo así. Busqué la palabra **setDelay** (para ver si se estaba modificando el delay del *Timer* desde algún lado) en la carpeta del proyecto y sólo aparece en un archivo `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core/12345.index` que no puedo leer porque está compilado.

Lo que tampoco entiendo es por qué no funciona a 100**fps** incluso después de quitar toda la lógica del método tick.

¿Alguna idea de qué puede ser?

En clase que hereda de JPanel e implementa ActionListener en la librería externa:

```
  // en el constructor llama a setDoubleBuffered(true);        
  public void iniciar(){
    iniciado = true;
    timer = new Timer(10, this);
    timer.start();        
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paint(g);
    g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    
    try
    {
        if (iniciado)
            juego.tick();
        
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
    g2d = null;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    repaint();
}
```

En clase Juego:

```
public void tick(){
  // HACER NADA
  if(time > (System.currentTimeMillis()) % 1000) {
     System.out.println(fps);  // output: 64(+-1)
     fps = 0;
  }
  fps++;
  time = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
}
```

---

(Hasta ahora la hipótesis más sólida es que se trata de algún chiste con la propiedad del sistema "`java.awt.headless`" y alguna implementación que hayan hecho del método sync de *Toolkit*).

Comment: Es una pregunta bastannnte amplia. Puede ser simplemente que en la universidad hay más recursos de hardware disponibles y, sin saber cómo está el Timer implementado, puede que no esté exacto al tiempo sino a los ciclos de CPU. No sé, acá echando globos mirando al techo porque no veo código :P

Comment: El código, librería de entorno incluida, tiene 80kb aproximadamente. Y es la solución a un trabajo práctico de la universidad, supongo que no sería ético compartirlo completo. Podría recopilar las partes que considero relevantes como cuando se instancia el Timer, la clase que implementa el ActionListener, y demás; pero dudo que sirva de algo, o sí?

Comment: Todo? No, de acuerdo. Lo mínimo para poder saber algo? Definitivamente. No sabemos nada más allá de lo que dices acá y eso sólo permite imaginarnos escenarios y adivinar. Estás suponiendo que es por el tick y tú mismo ya probaste que no. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: La pc de la universidad por lo que vi es una pentium. La diferencia más notable es que tiene windows 7 en vez de 10 como tengo yo y calculo que mis compañeros. Y si estuviese ejecutando el código más rápido, al quitar la lógica del método tick debería funcionar aunque sea igual de rápido desde nuetras computadoras. Comparto una parte del código.

Comment: No fue correcto decir que sólo ejecuta el método tick. Supongo que el problema puede estar en el JPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es ningún misterio... la misma [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) lo dice, te lo traduzco:

> Esta clase no ofrece garantías de tiempo-real: programa tareas usando el método Object.wait(long).

y en la documentacion de [Object.wait(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-)

> La cantidad de tiempo real que ha transcurrido, más o menos.

y si eso no fuera suficiente también usa internamente [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/util/Timer.java#L193) del cual podemos leer en su [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--)

> Note que mientras que la unidad de tiempo del valor de retorno es un milisegundo, la granuliaridad del valor depende del sistema operativo subyacente, y podría ser mayor. Por ejemplo, muchos sistemas operativos miden el tiempo en unidades de decenas de milisegundos.

### Que opciones hay?

#### ScheduledThreadPoolExecutors

Como este internamente usa `System.nanoTime()` no tiene ese problema

#### Awaitility

Esta librería [awaitility](/questions/tagged/awaitility) viene pensada para ser usada de modo funcional por lo que semánticamente puede aportar más a tu código, esta es a opción que yo más recomiendo a pesar de que tiene curva de aprendizaje.

Comment: Aclaro que el timer usado no era el de la página de la documentación mencionada, sino el de javax.swing.Timer. Igual, si es como decís, supongo que habrán cambiado alguna librería de los métodos nativos o algo así.